# Apache - strange time-to-first-byte issue

Tags: linux, apache

Somehow I think there's a problem with stat in linux, but I tested a regular empty folder in linux vs an icon of less than 1000 bytes in size. The test was done with Apache 2.2 and the server location is in east canada.

Webpagetest results: 
http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160202_KK_9HJ/1/details/

I'm curious as to why the time to first byte for the directory listing is higher than the time to first byte for the icon by one third?

What settings do I use in linux to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The time to first byte represents the time taken to 1) send the request to the server, 2) process the request and 3) return at least some of the results from the server.

For similarly sized resources 1) and 3) should be the same so let's concentrate on 2) for now.

When you request the directory, Apache has to check if the directory contains an index.html file, if not it reads the directory, then it starts to construct the HTML page creating links to the parent directory and each file/sub directory in the directory, then it has to return the file.

When you request the ico file Apache just has to pick up the file and return it to you nice and simple.

So as you can see there is more work in the first than in the second. So I don't think this is a fair test. Compare a static index.html file to a static ico file for a fairer test and then you'll know if you have an issue.

Additionally, depending on your mpm choice, settings, server load and server history there may be a thread or process started up waiting to process the first request (fast) or the first request may have to initiate one to handle this request (slow). This is likely to be less of an issue for a second request, particularly with keep-alive enabled. See here for more details: https://serverfault.com/questions/383526/how-do-i-select-which-apache-mpm-to-use.

There is also the [TCP slow start issue](https://www.igvita.com/2011/10/20/faster-web-vs-tcp-slow-start/), which particularly affects older version of OS and software, but that is unlikely to have an impact here in the small loads you are talking about and also should affect total download time rather than TTFB. Still it's yet another reason to ensure you're running up to date software.

And finally your TTFB is mostly influenced by your hosting provider and the pipes to your server and number of hops until
It gets to Apache so, once you have chosen a hosting provider, it is mostly out of your control. Again this will usually be reflective across the board and rather than the variances you see between two requests here.